# can't stop a Runnable that passing itself in ScheduledExecutorService.schedule

Tags: java, runnable, executorservice

I have a poller implemented from Runnable. The poller passes itself into a ScheduledExecutorService. Since I need different delay time depending on the tasks, I use 'schedule' instead of 'scheduleWithFixedDelay', which got a problem...

Unfortunately, this poller can't shut down properly...

The log shows that:
at beginning, 'main' thread schedules a poller;
after that, 'poller18' (or whatever thread id) thread schedules the following pollers.

When destroyed,
'main' thread calls destroy, set the flag  to true, and then call poller.shutdown;
but 'poller18' thread never see that flag (it is always false in schedulePoller), so it will keep scheduling next pollers.

My questions are:
1. isShuttingDown is a private field in the class. I thought it would be shared by the threads since it is not ThreadLocal. Why isn't it?
2. in this situation, is there any other way poller18 can be notified that poller is shutting down?

```
class Poller implements Runnable {
    private boolean isShuttingDown = false;
    private ScheduledExecutorService poller = null;

    @PostConstruct
    protected synchronized void start() {
      if (enabled && poller == null) {
          poller = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
          schedulePoller(1);
      }
   }

   protected synchronized void schedulePoller(final long period) {
      if (poller() == null || poller().isShutdown() || this.isShuttingDown) {
          return;
      }
      LOGGER.info("schedule a new poller");
      poller().schedule(this,
              period,
              TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }

   public void run() {
      ... do work ...
      if (more work)
           schedulePoller(1);
      else
           schedulePoller(10);
   }

   public void destroy() {
      this.isShuttingDown = true;
      poller.shutdown();
      while (!poller.awaitTermination(SHUTDOWN_WAIT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
          LOGGER.info("Waiting for remaining tasks to finish.");
          poller.shutdown();
      }
      LOGGER.info("All remaining tasks have finished.");
   }
}
```

And in spring config, I set destroy_method to destroy().

Many thanks! Please let me know if any confusions in my description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing the shared state (isShuttingDown), whether it is read or write access, you need to always hold the same lock in order to have consistent shared state between threads.
destroy() method is not synchronized and therefore does not hold a the same object lock(the implicit lock on the current/"this" class instance), while it changes the shared state variable. 
This is most probably why isShuttingDown is not seen correctly by all threads...

Comment: Thanks! It might be one of the reason.  My first try is: synchronized the entire destroy() method but it then got deadlock (destroy() is waiting for a thread to finish while holding the lock, run() is going to schedulePoller() before it's done which is waiting for that lock).  My second try: use block synchronize, i.e. instead of awaitTermination, use isTerminate and block that single line, if it is not terminate yet, sleep. This time, it will release the lock and then sleep so that a current thread can complete its task.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
private volatile boolean isShuttingDown = false;
```

[Thread Pooling](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/threads/chap13.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc isn't very clear regarding the behavior of new schedules if the executor is shutting down. In my understanding, it should reject new schedules.

Anyway, the poller thread doesn't see the value of your flag because it's not synchronized. You need to synchronize all its accesses, or to make it volatile. Another way is to use an AtomicBoolean, which will encapsulate this for you.

Comment: I did. In my code, I have setter and getter for isShuttingDown which are synchronized.